# Creating a clean function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the massive block of JS below. What steps can I take to clean it up as it the same function iterated for different div each time. Im throwing this out there as a general question as Im not sure what can be done to simplify code like this.

```
$(function() {
    $('#1').hover(function() {
      $('#1-pin').find('.pin-bounce').addClass('pin-hovered');
    }, function() {
      $('#1-pin').find('.pin-bounce').removeClass('pin-hovered');
    });
  });

  $(function() {
    $('#2').hover(function() {
      $('#2-pin').find('.pin-bounce').addClass('pin-hovered');
    }, function() {
      $('#2-pin').find('.pin-bounce').removeClass('pin-hovered');
    });
  });

  $(function() {
    $('#3').hover(function() {
      $('#3-pin').find('.pin-bounce').addClass('pin-hovered');
    }, function() {
      $('#3-pin').find('.pin-bounce').removeClass('pin-hovered');
    });
  });

  $(function() {
    $('#4').hover(function() {
      $('#4-pin').find('.pin-bounce').addClass('pin-hovered');
    }, function() {
      $('#4-pin').find('.pin-bounce').removeClass('pin-hovered');
    });
  });

  $(function() {
    $('#5').hover(function() {
      $('#5-pin').find('.pin-bounce').addClass('pin-hovered');
    }, function() {
      $('#5-pin').find('.pin-bounce').removeClass('pin-hovered');
    });
  });
  $(function() {
    $('#6').hover(function() {
      $('#6-pin').find('.pin-bounce').addClass('pin-hovered');
    }, function() {
      $('#6-pin').find('.pin-bounce').removeClass('pin-hovered');
    });
  });
```

Comment: For 4 and 6, you have an exception of `tracking` and `events`?

Comment: Loop over the numbers and build your selectors with it? More suited for code review stack exchange, no?

Comment: Do you know the number of elements? Think of a loop.

Comment: Could you add a sample of your HTML to the question? If you follow DRY principles it should be easy to put this all in to a single click handler based on a class and some data attributes. There is no loops necessary, despite what others are saying.

Comment: it might be possible with `this`, but your html would determine how good or bad of a solution that could be. Impossible to tell right now because you don't include your markup.

Comment: Try to use CLASS instead of ID

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that the .pin-bounce is a child, you could create one hover function that works off of a common class and then inside of that just look for the class.

```
$('.some-common-class-instead-of-id').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.pin-bounce').addClass('pin-hovered');
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.pin-bounce').removeClass('pin-hovered');
});
```

If it's not a child you could do something similar but instead of just finding children, you could build up a string like this:

```
$('.some-common-class-instead-of-id').hover(function() {
  var idToFind = $(this).attr('id') + '-pin';
  $('#' + idToFind).find('.pin-bounce').addClass('pin-hovered');
}, function() {
  var idToFind = $(this).attr('id') + '-pin';
  $('#' + idToFind).find('.pin-bounce').removeClass('pin-hovered');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    (function(i){
        $('#'+i).hover(function() {
           $('#'+i+'-pin').find('.pin-bounce').addClass('pin-hovered');
        }, function() {
           $('#'+i+'-pin').find('.pin-bounce').removeClass('pin-hovered');
        });
    })(i);

}
```

Comment: good solution for this problem but not generic as instead of number if name appears in random order.

Comment: @Sumit - I know. It is not a generic solution though I never intended for one. Anyways thank you for mentioning.